# "is not registered with iMessage" iPad mini to iPhone 4

Tags: ios, ipad, iphone, messages

So I recently asked a girl to text me, and I put my email on her phone, but she never texted me because it said "not registered with iMessage" even though I am. Then, I asked her for her phone number and when I tried to text it, it said "is not registered with iMessage". We both have iMessage and we both made sure we gave each other the proper address. I have an iPad mini 1 and I think she has an iPhone 4 or something. Can anyone help me with this???

Comment: Are you updated to the latest iOS?

Comment: I have iOS 9, but not iOS 9.1 yet... Do you think that will help?

Comment: maybe. If not, try turning iMessage of and then on in Settings.

Comment: Ok I'll try that and tell you what happened... Thanks :)

Comment: Nope... As much as I hate to say it, it still says she's not registered with imessage

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have that email address selected in the list in Settings > Messages > iMessage

[image]

Comment: Tetsujin thanks for answering me! I have the iPad and she has the iPhone and the email I gave her is in that so, if you have any other suggestions it is much appreciated :) Thanks

Comment: You both checked this on your phone/pad, that the address you each are using is registered in your own phone/pad?